# how to check if a web form element exists with selenium

Tags: testing, selenium, web

I need to check if a form element exists in my current web page with selenium.
Does anybody know how to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. Either use lefthandedgoat's version catching an exception, or use the FindElements method and check it's size, so something like (in C# using LINQ):

```
public bool IsElementPresent(By selector)
{
    return driver.FindElements(selector).Any();
}
```

Either option will work fine, there is not really much different. I personally use the other way, but wanted to make sure you knew there are generally two ways to do this. You didn't mention a language, so let us know if there is a specific language you are using.

It is worth noting that underneath, when you do a FindElement() in Selenium, it is performing this method.

Comment: Thank you, actually i was using Selenium IDE...is there a way to do the same thing with the IDE version?

Comment: I tried to resolve my issue with this set of commands :

    <tr>
 <td>verifyElementPresent</td>
 <td>//*[@id=&quot;civilite&quot;]</td>
 <td>resultVerif</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>storeEval</td>
 <td>(storedVars['resultVerif']==true)?echo['okay']:echo['not okay']);</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
 but i have a : [error] Threw an exception: missing ; before statement

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

In the C# version of selenium it will throw an exception if the element does not exist.  You could do something like this

```
public bool Exists(string cssSelector)
{
  try
  {
    browser.FindElement(By.CssSelector(cssSelector));
    return true
  }
  catch (Exception ex){}

  return false;
}


var exists = Exists("form");
```

I am not sure how the webdriver behaves in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pair of methods:

```
input.findElements(By.xpath("//....blablalba....")).size() > 0

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//....blablalba....")).isDisplayed()
```